# Excel VBA - Split string with variable delimiter count

Tags: vba, split

How I can split the string with variable delimiter count:

```
s = "a1 b2    c  d    e"
```

into array:

```
arr(1) = "a1"
arr(2) = "b2"
arr(4) = "c"
arr(5) = "d"
arr(6) = "e"
```

The split-function does not give a desired result:

```
arr = Split(s, " ")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Side note, don't use `Str` as a variable name... you're shadowing the [`Str`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`WorksheetFunction.Trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.trim) to remove leading and trailing spaces, as well as extra inner spaces.

```
Dim s As String '<~ don't use Str
s = "a b    c  d    e"
    
s = WorksheetFunction.Trim(s)
```

Comment: I am now waiting for the the, "This will not work as my delimiter is not actually a space but something else." comment.

Comment: @scot-craner  In my case is delimiter a space character :)

Answer (score 0):

The pure VBA approach is to use a loop and the replace function

```
Public Function Dedup(ByVal ipSource As String, ByVal ipDedup As String) As String

    Dim mySource As String
    mySource = ipSource

    Dim MyDedupDedup As String
    MyDedupDedup = ipDedup & ipDedup
    
    Do
    
        DoEvents ' Always put a doevents in a Do loop
        Dim myLen As Long
        myLen = Len(mySource)
        mySource = Replace(mySource, MyDedupDedup, ipDedup)
        
    Loop Until myLen = Len(mySource)
    
    Dedup = mySource
    
End Function
```

If you have leading or trailing characters you can use a more flexible trim function

```
Public Function Trimmer(ByVal ipString As String, Optional ByVal ipTrimChars As String = " ,;" & vbCrLf & vbTab) As String

    Dim myString As String
    myString = ipString
    
    Dim myIndex As Long
    For myIndex = 1 To 2
    
        If VBA.Len(myString) = 0 Then Exit For
    
        Do While VBA.InStr(ipTrimChars, VBA.Left$(myString, 1)) > 0
              
            DoEvents ' Always put a do event statement in a do loop
            
            myString = VBA.Mid$(myString, 2)
            
        Loop
        
        myString = VBA.StrReverse(myString)
    
    Next
    
    Trimmer = myString
    
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In my case, the function "WorksheetFunction.Trim" is sufficient.